# Update the token ownership on Ethescan

Tags: tokens, etherscan

Recently, I deployed a token and followed this link to verify token ownership:
https://info.etherscan.com/how-to-verify-address-ownership/

I soon realized my account on the Etherscan is not the right account to become owner of the token. I have to transform/update the ownership to another account.

Is it possible to update ownership of a token on the Etherscan?

Comment: Etherscan is a private company. You have to [reach out](https://etherscan.io/contactus) to them, there's nothing that anyone in this forum can help you with.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't find any rule against asking about private companies in the meta. I thought maybe someone has the same issue and the solution.

Comment: Actually there is a rule: `This question does not appear to be about Ethereum, the decentralized application platform and smart contract enabled blockchain`. Etherscan is tightly coupled to Ethereum, for sure, but the answer to your question is basically "reach out to Etherscan support".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send an email to etherscan asking them to release your ownership through their contactus [contactus](https://etherscan.io/contactus) page. Afterwards, the correct account can claim ownership.

UPDATE

In contactus page, select "Support / Technical Issue" as subject.
Then in "TOKEN UPDATES" section, you will find more details about ownership of a contract.

For releasing ownership, first you need to create a verified signed message, the following link explains how:

[How to Release Contract Address Ownership?](https://info.etherscan.com/how-to-release-contract-address-ownership/)

Come back to the contactus page. At the bottom of the page, there is a section for "ADDITIONAL SUPPORT". Here you can find a link to send them an email.

Actually that's how we did it on polygonscan. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I saw the contact us page, but I could not find the template message (probably just like what I used during asking for the ownership) to send the release ownership request.

Comment: @nsafari Updated my answer,